# Why they wrap code with anonymous function and call it immediately instead simple executing same code?

Tags: javascript

Investigating some .html file I found interesting JavaScript construction:

```
<script>
...
ga(
  function(tracker) {
    (
      function(w, d, c) {
        $.getScript(
          ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + "service.com/script.js?param;client_id"+c+";ref" + escape(d.referrer) + ";url" + escape(d.URL) + ";cook" + escape(d.cookie)
        );
      }
    ) (window, document, tracker.get('clientId'));
  }
);
</script>
```

There is some function 'ga' which takes a function as an input parameter and will do something with it in a future.

The question is about body of that anonymous function. Why they created one more internal anonymous function and call it immediately instead just executing the same code like this:

```
<script>
...
ga(
  function(tracker) {
    // I have changed d -> document, c -> tracker.get('clientId')
    $.getScript(
      ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + "service.com/script.js?param;client_id"+tracker.get('clientId')+";ref" + escape(document.referrer) + ";url" + escape(document.URL) + ";cook" + escape(document.cookie)
    );
  }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I would ask the same question, because it's the same thing. I suppose the coder wanted to make it easier to modify the code. I think the first one looks better and easier to understand than your suggested code.

Comment: `ga` is for Google Analytics. I wouldn't go messing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ali's answer might be the correct answer if you were looking for a reason to use functions in general. But what you are talking about Alexey Ruzin I believe is a closure. something along these lines :

```
(function called(arguments){
    // statements here
})();
```

This is done to protect the data and it's scope. So you know that your variables can only be used inside of the scope.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

There could be several reasons behind it.

One reason is to simplify the multiple use of a single expression. For example, in your code snippet you had to use the `document` multiple times whereas the original code is much shorter as the inner functions uses 1-letter long names for the variables.
This will become more significant if you have to use a longer expression multiple times in a small portion of a code.